# HTML Table : addition of value from one column(each row) and 2nd column and dispaly it on third column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

(Table will be fetched from database so it will be having N number of rows)

I could get the result on console using 'td:nth-child(7)' but I want in on change of 'td:nth-child(5)' or 'td:nth-child(6)'

Here i am getting console value but cant get it in column text

http://jsfiddle.net/adwaitrao/s78y031x/11/

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  var text0 = $row.find('td:nth-child(5)').text();
  var text1 = $row.find('td:nth-child(6)').text();
  var str = $row.find('td:nth-child(7)').text();
  var res = +text0 + +text1;
  console.log(res);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Sr</td>
    <td>Product name</td>
    <td>Variants</td>
    <td>Attributes</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Result </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>department1</td>
    <td>Colorred</td>
    <td contenteditable>4</td>
    <td contenteditable>720</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><button class="btn">ADD TRANSACTION</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>department2</td>
    <td>Colorgreen</td>
    <td contenteditable>6</td>
    <td contenteditable>900</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><button class="btn">ADD TRANSACTION</button></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Show us the code, we all understand code, sometimes we dont understand the prose

Comment: Are you using PHP to execute your query?

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```js
function show()  {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  var text0 = $row.find('td:nth-child(5)').text();
  var text1 = $row.find('td:nth-child(6)').text();
  var str = $row.find('td:nth-child(7)').text();
  var res = +text0 + +text1;
  console.log(res);
}
$(".btn").on("click",show);
$("[contenteditable]").on("input",show)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Sr</td>
    <td>Product name</td>
    <td>Variants</td>
    <td>Attributes</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Result </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Product1</td>
    <td>department1</td>
    <td>Colorred</td>
    <td contenteditable>4</td>
    <td contenteditable>720</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><button class="btn">ADD TRANSACTION</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Product2</td>
    <td>department2</td>
    <td>Colorgreen</td>
    <td contenteditable>6</td>
    <td contenteditable>900</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><button class="btn">ADD TRANSACTION</button></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: not exactly i just want to show addition of (Price and qty) on result

Comment: What result - where